# Custom Header and Footer for both new and existing documents

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, footers

I edited the "Normal" template to include the header and footer that i want. it works as expected only on new documents. Is there a way to define header and footer that will be automatically added to all documents (both existing and new) in Microsoft office 2007 ?.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft office 2007 we can add same header and footer for all the pages as same by selecting the option "Insert the same header or footer on each page". You have two methods,

1)Predefined header or footer
2)Custom header or footer

In the top you can able to find 'Insert Tab', select that add the header or footer by choosing "Insert the same header or footer on each page". This will help you to add same header and footer in all the document.

Answer (score 0):

New documents based on your amended Normal.dot template should have the header and footer added by default.  But subsequent changes to Normal.dot will not be reflected in an existing document unless that document has the `Automatically Update Document Styles` box checked.  This option is found through `Developer Tab | Document Template`.

When MS Word creates a new document from a template it usually *copies* the formatting info from the template into the new doc and then never refers to the template again.  That is, unless that update option is checked.  If you switch this on in an old document and then reopen it it'll update to match the amended template, but to work properly Word relies on you having amended the named Styles in the template that are also used in the document.  You may not get the behavior you expect if you've changed bits of formatting without using Styles.

Also, be careful if you share this automatically updating document with someone, because it will update to match *their* Normal.dot, which won't include your template amendments.

The ever reliable Shauna Kelly has a good break down of how MS Word uses templates: http://shaunakelly.com/word/sharing/willmyformatchange.html